# Android - start service from its object

Tags: android, object, service

I'm developing an application that will upload files to **Firebase storage** by means of some methods.To do this I use background **service** in order to avoid interruption that can be cause some bugs.

---

The problem is my **service class** should get some objects such as

```
public  StorageReference stoageRefer;
public  Uri fileUri;
public UploadFinishedListener uploadFinishedListener;
```

---

To use these objects i created setter which will help me to modify them.

```
 public void setStoageRefer(StorageReference stoageRefer) {
    this.stoageRefer = stoageRefer;
}

public void setFileUri(Uri fileUri) {
    this.fileUri = fileUri;
}

public void setUploadFinishedListener(UploadFinishedListener uploadFinishedListener) {
    this.uploadFinishedListener = uploadFinishedListener;
}
```

---

From my activity class from which I will start this service and set them on my service object:

```
    UploaderService uploaderService = new UploaderService();

    uploaderService.setFileUri(fileUri);
    uploaderService.setStoageRefer(stoageRefer);
    uploaderService.setUploadFinishedListener(new UploadFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnUploadFinished(Uri Uri) {
            UserModel.setmImageUri(Uri.toString());
            mDatabase.child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("DailyStory").setValue(UserModel);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Actually, i *tried* one way that **won't be useful**.All set objects were **null**;

> <strike>startService(new Intent(this, uploaderService.getClass()));</strike>

---

My whole service class code: UploaderService.class

```
public class UploaderService extends Service {


public StorageReference stoageRefer;
public Uri fileUri;
public UploadFinishedListener uploadFinishedListener;
Notification notification;

public void setStoageRefer(StorageReference stoageRefer) {
    this.stoageRefer = stoageRefer;
}

public void setFileUri(Uri fileUri) {
    this.fileUri = fileUri;
}

public void setUploadFinishedListener(UploadFinishedListener uploadFinishedListener) {
    this.uploadFinishedListener = uploadFinishedListener;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    startToUpload();

}

public void NotificationProgress(int progress) {

    Integer notificationID = 100;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("File is uploading")
            .setContentText("It may take a while...")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.clagra_logo)
            .setProgress(100, progress, false);


    notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);

}

public void cancelNotification(Context ctx, int notifyId) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
}

public void startToUpload() {

    UploadTask uploadTask = stoageRefer.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUri.getPath())));


    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

            Log.d("uploadFail", "" + exception);

            Toast.makeText(UploaderService.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            stopSelf();

        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            uploadFinishedListener.OnUploadFinished(downloadUrl);

            cancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), 100);

            stopSelf();

        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

            NotificationProgress((int) progress);

            Log.v("TAgTAG", progress + "");

        }
    });


}


public final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public UploaderService getService() {
        return UploaderService.this;
    }
}
```

}

---

Now I want to know is there any way to startActivity or Service from its object.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: use Bind service .

Comment: Please explain a little bit...

Comment: 'Service' is a component and can not be initialize with  `new` keyword. Start Service with intent  Use Ibinder to communicate . Read [Bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Comment: I tried many ways but i couldn't understant, please could you post answer to get instance of service and use it... Thanks in advance...

Comment: first question is, I have posted Bound service link did you follow the documentation? and second is, add your service code above

Comment: Yes, I also found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297)  but couldn't understand the var **mConnection** and how to use it to communicate with service.

Comment: onStartCommand() is missing in your service class.

Comment: Okay I added it, then I set my objects to the instance of service class

uploaderService.setFileUri(fileUri);
        uploaderService.setStoageRefer(stoageRefer);
        uploaderService.setUploadFinishedListener(new UploadFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnUploadFinished(Uri Uri) {
                UserModel.setmImageUri(Uri.toString());
                mDatabase.child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("DailyStory").setValue(UserModel);
                finish();
            }
        });

Now how can I start service?

Comment: Are you using this service only for uploading purpose ? Means its not START_STICY(background) ? am i right ? If yes the follow [This tutorial](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android).